# Alterar linguagem no github

Tags: git, github

Tenho um projeto desenvolvido em Python com Django.
Acabei de criar um repositório e dar o pull no github e o projeto foi setado como sendo de PHP no site do Github:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Algumas imagens do meu projeto e seus arquivos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então:

- Alguém sabe como e porque o Github fez essa escolha? Eu não tenho nenhum arquivo php nesse projeto. (Quando criei essa pergunta eu me enganei. Veja na minha resposta que eu tinha 2 arquivos .php sim)
- Como eu altero a linguagem para Python?

Comment: Vc só enviou para o repositório ou vc está tentando publicar como GitPage ?

Comment: Eu criei um repositório no site do github e subi o projeto nele.
O estranho é que subi o mesmo projeto no GitLab e não aconteceu isso.
Queria entender o que o Github usou como base para decidir por PHP, sendo que nao tenho nenhum arquivo php no projeto

Comment: @hugocsl não tem nada haver com gitpage a questão é sobre o repositório mesmo.

Comment: Não tem como saber porque ele apontou PHP se você não detalhar a pergunta, algo tem que ter no teu repositório.

Comment: Por acaso [este usuário](https://github.com/bussola?tab=repositories)? Pois bem, na listagem geral não mostra nada em PHP

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu perguntei pq o GitPagem não aceita nada além de html/css/js, então poderia estar dando algum alerta "genérico" caso ele estivesse tentando publicar como Page

Comment: É porque o repositório está como particular. Somente eu tenho acesso a ele @JeffersonQuesado

Comment: Engraçado que você afirmou ***"Eu não tenho nenhum arquivo php nesse projeto."***, suas palavras, mas aceitou a pergunta que elimina no linguist os arquivos .php, ou seja na verdade existe sim arquivos .php, eu ia responder, mas evitei pelo simples fato de poderem ser arquivos com "extensões primas" no php como `.phtml` ou `.php3`, ai se eu responde-se poderia dar certo ou não, faz o que eu disse no outro comentário, clique na bolinha azul ao lado do "PHP" e veja os arquivos que aparecem e tira um print.

Comment: @hugocsl a pergunta é sobre o LINGUIST e não sobre PHP funcionar em githubpages, tanto que ele não mencionou nada sobre executar PHP, mas sim sobre o linguist não funcionar como esperado quando usado no automático.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Descobri o que era.
Primeiramente, como o @GuilhermeNascimento já tinha alertado em algum comentário, minha pergunta está errada, pois descobri que dentro do meu arquivo ***static*** existem sim 2 arquivos .php.

- Então sim, existem arquivos *.php* no meu projeto (Apesar de serem somente 2);
- A resposta do @Max infelizmente não funcionou, não sei o porque;

**Conclusão dos meus testes com o arquivo `.gitattributes`:**

- Colocando apenas **** linguist-vendored*** o github *retira* a informação da linguagem, deixando esse campo em branco;
- Precisei desconsiderar minha pasta **static**, onde haviam os 2 arquivos *.php*;
- Como o projeto foi desenvolvido em Django, tive que desconsiderar as pastas dos meus templates, para que o github nao entenda o projeto como sendo *.html*

Meu arquivo **.gitattributes** ficou assim:

```
static/* linguist-vendored
site_cartao/static/* linguist-vendored
site_cartao/templates/* linguist-vendored
```

E o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 6):

O Github usa a biblioteca **Linguist** para determinar a porcentagem de cada linguagem em um projeto e gerar aquela barra maneira lá em cima, contudo, não está livre de falhas.

O método mais rápido de resolver isso é criar um arquivo chamado `.gitattributes` na raiz do seu diretório e lá colocar as seguintes linhas:

```
* linguist-vendored
*.php linguist-vendored=false
```

Assim ele vai ignorar os arquivos do tipo .`php`. Na teoria é pra correção funcionar retroativamente já no commit deste arquivo, mas caso não funcione você pode deletar e criar um novo projeto com este arquivo já por default.

Você pode também dizer qual linguagem quer que ele aponte como sendo a do projeto:

```
*.python linguist-detectable=true
```

Não esqueça também de ir no [repo da biblioteca](https://github.com/github/linguist) e abrir uma issue com o seu problema.

Comment: Ok, isto resolve, mas claramente o que o autor afirmou então não é verdade, porque se é necessário o false para `*.php` então significa que tem sim arquivos .PHP, o que foi o motivo de ninguém ter respondido até agora, porque ele disse exatamente isto: **Alguém sabe como e porque o Github fez essa escolha? Eu não tenho nenhum arquivo php nesse projeto.**, e poderia ser outra extensão que teria causado o problema, alguma extensão coincidentemente "prima do php", como .php3 ou phtml.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento realmente não existem arquivos .php no repositório...
O projeto é todo em python mesmo...

Comment: @ViniciusBussola mas não importa, o problema é que tem alguma extensão "prima" que não é de fato PHP mas esta confundindo, o repositório é PUBLICO ou privado? Com certeza tem algo errado, faça o seguinte, clique na bolinha azul ao lado do "PHP", ele vai exibir os arquivos que causaram isto no linguist.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o repositorio é privado infelizmente.. 
A bolinha azul nao é clicavel tb..
Assim que descobrir o que causou isso compartilho aqui